# my data return me proto object Redux with sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, redux-saga

I would like to get my state of ACTIONS: LOAD_GROUP but object return me 
proto: Object
[image]

My sagas.js

```
##//SAGAS ##
import { loadGroup } from "../actions/Group"

export function* loadApiDataGroup() {
  try {
    // API 
        const response = yield call(axios.get, 'http://localhost:8000/api/group');
        yield put(loadGroup(response))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('REQUEST FAILED! Could not get group.')
    console.log(e)
  }
}

export default function* mySaga() {
  yield [
    loadApiDataGroup(),
  ]
}
```

actions.js

```
##// ACTIONS ##
export function loadGroup(data){ return { type: LOAD_GROUP, data }};

## // REDUCER ##
export default function groupReducer( state= {}, action = {}){
    switch (action.type){
        case LOAD_GROUP:
            return {
                ...state
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

root.js

```
## // ROOT REDUCERS ##
import groupReducer from '../actions/Group'

const reducer = combineReducers({
  groupReducer,
});
```

my coponent

```
## // COMPONENT ##
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    console.log(state., "CONSOLE LOG");
    return {
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { actions: bindActionCreators({ loadGroup }, dispatch)};
}
```

Comment: Your state is empty since you didn't update initialState with the response of your api call. Update your reducer to this
` case LOAD_GROUP:
            return {
                ...state,
               group: action.data
            }`

Comment: Thank you Brandon, it's was that ! :)